# Could not find method applicationId() for arguments?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have tried to fix this error, but I don't know what it the main problem in my case.

The error I get is about adding dependencies or the version of my dependencies if there is a solution please help:

My gradle file :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the app.gradle file is :

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> ```
> android {
>
>     compileSdkVersion 28
>     buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
>
>     defaultConfig
>         applicationId "me.ismashot.ibtassim"
>         minSdkVersion 15
>         targetSdkVersion 28
>         versionCode 59
>         versionName '4.6'
>         multiDexEnabled true
>     }
>
>     dexOptions {
>
>         jumboMode true
>     }
>
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
>
>     lintOptions {
>         checkReleaseBuilds false
>         // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
>         // but continue the build even when errors are found:
>         abortOnError false
>     }
>
>     productFlavors {
>     }
>
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation  fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>     implementation  'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
>     implementation  'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
>     implementation  'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
>     implementation  'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
>     implementation  'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
>     implementation  'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
>     implementation  'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
>     implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
>     implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3'
>     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
>     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
>
>     implementation  files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```

Anyone help me fixing this issue with my application guys ?

Comment: Where do you get that error? Please paste the entire error and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: this is the error : Could not find method applicationId() for arguments [me.ismashot.ibtassim] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: it linked to the app.gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the missing `{` to your `defaultConfig`:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.ismashot.ibtassim"
        ...
        }
    ...
}
```

**Edit:**

For fixing `Failed to resolve: play-services-basement` make sure to bring `google()` repository before `jcenter()` in the all `repositories` blocks:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar

Comment: this is what i got for this problem

Comment: @ismail I'm not sure I follow. Is your problem fixed?

Comment: Sir, i just need to fix this : Failed to resolve: play-services-basement